# how to set font size based on container size?

Tags: javascript, css, font-size

I have a container that has a % width and height, so it scales depending on external factors. I would like the font inside the container to be a constant size relative to the size of containers. Is there any good way to do this using CSS? The `font-size: x%` would only scale the font according to the original font size (which would be 100%).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may be able to do this with CSS3 using calculations, however it would most likely be safer to use JavaScript.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8TrTU/

Using JS you can change the height of the text, then simply bind this same calculation to a resize event, during resize so it scales while the user is making adjustments, or however you are allowing resizing of your elements.

Comment: Try using: ```window.onresize = function(event) { yourFunctionHere(); };``` as well, this way if the user decides to resize their page after it has loaded your font will resize appropriately

Answer (score 153):

If you want to set the font-size as a percentage of the viewport width, use the `vw`unit:

```css
#mydiv { font-size: 5vw; }
```

The other alternative is to use SVG embedded in the HTML. It will just be a few lines. The font-size attribute to the text element will be interpreted as "user units", for instance those the viewport is defined in terms of. So if you define viewport as 0 0 100 100, then a font-size of 1 will be one one-hundredth of the size of the svg element.

And no, there is no way to do this in CSS using calculations. The problem is that percentages used for font-size, including percentages inside a calculation, are interpreted in terms of the inherited font size, not the size of the container. CSS could use a unit called `bw` (box-width) for this purpose, so you could say `div { font-size: 5bw; }`, but I've never heard this proposed.

Comment: What browsers does vw work on ? I can't get it to work in firefox.

Comment: @lorefnon, this page http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units says it will work in Firefox 19, meanwhile try Chrome.

Comment: @torazburo, Hmm, tried it in FF 17.0. Great find btw, had no idea something like this existed.

Comment: I've hacked together a piece of less code that will use vw where available and fallback predefined values for various media queries: https://gist.github.com/tnajdek/5143504

Comment: I came here because `vw` is the opposite of what I need, and found this answer...which has nothing to do with the question.. :(

Comment: for anyone interested in the cross browser support of this: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Comment: Note that `vw` is relative to the viewport, not to the container size. Probably useful in many cases, but svg worked better for me.

Comment: If the parent container's height or width is a percentage like 40% or 70%, what would we put down for vh or vw? That is what the question of this post asked about originally.

Answer (score 70):

Another js alternative:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/8TrTU/481/)**

```
fontsize = function () {
    var fontSize = $("#container").width() * 0.10; // 10% of container width
    $("#container h1").css('font-size', fontSize);
};
$(window).resize(fontsize);
$(document).ready(fontsize);
```

Or as stated in [torazaburo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13789877/1947286) you could use svg. I put together a simple example as a proof of concept:

**[SVG Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Xyb79/1/)**

```
<div id="container">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 13 15">
        <text x="0" y="13">X</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a comment, take a look how 'firefox' opens and display a .pdf file. It's javascriptly resizing the content. Quite heavy, but fully working.

Comment: This totally worked for me , now I just need to center the text vertically

Answer (score 7):

I used [Fittext](http://fittextjs.com/) on some of my projects and it looks like a good solution to a problem like this.

> FitText makes font-sizes flexible. Use this plugin on your fluid or responsive layout to achieve scalable headlines that fill the width of a parent element.

Comment: Yep FitText is great and simple to setup

Answer (score 6):

It **cannot** be accomplished with css [font-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-size)

Assuming that "external factors" you are referring to could be picked up by media queries, you could use them - adjustments will likely have to be limited to a set of predefined sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function:

```
document.body.setScaledFont = function(f) {
  var s = this.offsetWidth, fs = s * f;
  this.style.fontSize = fs + '%';
  return this
};
```

Then convert all your documents child element font sizes to em's or %.

Then add something like this to your code to set the base font size.

```
document.body.setScaledFont(0.35);
window.onresize = function() {
    document.body.setScaledFont(0.35);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0tpvccjt/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but I had to consider other issues that @apaul34208 example did not tackle. In my case;

- I have a container that changed size depending on the viewport using media queries
- Text inside is dynamically generated
- I want to scale up as well as down

Not the most elegant of examples but it does the trick for me. Consider using throttling the window resize (https://lodash.com/)

```js
var TextFit = function(){
 var container = $('.container');
  container.each(function(){
    var container_width = $(this).width(),
      width_offset = parseInt($(this).data('width-offset')),
        font_container = $(this).find('.font-container');
 
     if ( width_offset > 0 ) {
         container_width -= width_offset;
     }
                
    font_container.each(function(){
      var font_container_width = $(this).width(),
          font_size = parseFloat( $(this).css('font-size') );

      var diff = Math.max(container_width, font_container_width) - Math.min(container_width, font_container_width);
 
      var diff_percentage = Math.round( ( diff / Math.max(container_width, font_container_width) ) * 100 );
      
      if (diff_percentage !== 0){
          if ( container_width > font_container_width ) {
            new_font_size = font_size + Math.round( ( font_size / 100 ) * diff_percentage );
          } else if ( container_width < font_container_width ) {
            new_font_size = font_size - Math.round( ( font_size / 100 ) * diff_percentage );
          }
      }
      $(this).css('font-size', new_font_size + 'px');
    });
  });
}

$(function(){
  TextFit();
  $(window).resize(function(){
   TextFit();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width:341px;
  height:341px;
  background-color:#000;
  padding:20px;
 }
 .font-container {
  font-size:131px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" data-width-offset="10">
 <span class="font-container">£5000</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Merch80/b8hoctfb/7/

Answer (score 0):

I've given a more detailed answer of using `vw` with respect to specific container sizing [**in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container/19818026#19818026), so I won't just repeat my answer here.

In summary, however, it is essentially a matter of factoring (or controlling) what the container size is going to be with respect to viewport, and then working out the proper `vw` sizing based on that for the container, taking mind of what needs to happen if something is dynamically resized.

So if you wanted a `5vw` size at a container at 100% of the viewport width, then one at `75%` of the viewport width you would probably want to be `(5vw * .75) = 3.75vw`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale it depending on the element width, you can use this web component:
https://github.com/pomber/full-width-text

Check the demo here:
https://pomber.github.io/full-width-text/

The usage is like this:

```
<full-width-text>Lorem Ipsum</full-width-text>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also try this pure CSS method:

```
font-size: calc(100% - 0.3em);
```

Comment: that's not going to work at all. all this does is set the font size relatively to the containers font size. (minus 0.3 em)