# How do I scale a group of text tags relative to the size of a page?

Tags: css, text, svg, resize

I've been messing with this for weeks, so I'm just gonna flat out ask how to do it.

I've been working on a little SVG countdown clock just for the hell of it. But when I try and position things relative to how the page might be sized, I get stuck. I can't seem to size `text` tags relative to the page, and I can't find a way to put them into a group for sizing.

I've tried putting them into `symbol` tags, and using `viewBox`, but I can't seem to get that to work either.

My intended goal is to have this working on any sized screen from monitors to smartphones. So I wanted to do something with a `min`, and `max width/height`, or something along those lines, and apply it to a combination of the number and it's associated label. So I would have one group for days with both the number of days(being changed by the script), and then the word "days" underneath it.

Here is what I'm working with if it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/2P9qV/

Does anyone have any ideas? I've been stumped for weeks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292001/how-to-set-font-size-based-on-container-size

Comment: Not quite. I wish this could be done with CSS, but I am sizing text tags in an SVG, which don't support that.

Comment: Not quite the right answer, but something like http://jsfiddle.net/2P9qV/1/ any use ?

Comment: kind of. But the issue is that with multiple types of devices(widescreen monitors, smartphones in landscape/portrait, etc), I can't just rely on a square.
My issue is that I wanted to create individual groups(not quite <g>s because I can't apply the viewBox to that) each with the number for the unit of time, and the word representing the unit of time below it. But even if I do that, I have no idea how to size the viewBox to make it fit properly, since I have no way measuring the width/height, or even relying on a set width/height of each, since they change.

Comment: I might try just making each one an SVG or something, and try getting the view box right there, and sizing/placing it that way though. I'll give it a shot and update later

Comment: Ok, figured it out. Check out my solution, if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out. Luckily, I was able to use multiple SVGs within an SVG to create content, and then display it using `use` tags.

So I had each set as part of it's own symbol in `defs`. From there, I used the viewBox on the `symbol` tag to limit the draw space to the exact width and height of the content created, which I found by inspecting the element, and using the height and width it had been made as(without the 'px'). This way, I could center the whole set in the SVG that had the `use` tag, then set the width of the SVG to 100%, and the height to the percentage I wanted to scale it to. Since these are set as percentages, the page will limit the SVG's size to whichever is most limiting, while still maintaining scale, so it won't skew.

So one of the symbols would be:

```
<symbol id="daysSymbol" viewBox="0 0 110 156">
    <g>
        <text id="days" y="0" x="50%" font-size="100" class="time big">00</text>
        <text id="daysT" y="100" x="50%" font-size="40" class="text bigText">DAYS</text>
    </g>
</symbol>
```

and the SVG for this would be

```
<svg id="daysSVG" height="50%" width="100%" y="30%"> 
    <use xlink:href="#daysSymbol" height="100%"/>
</svg>
```

It also let me get creative with how I managed the contents on the page. As something happened, I was able to dynamically remove content, and scale other elements to take up the new space.

For those curious, here is the final product

https://hostr.co/file/PLCY7lodb7Lk/xboxCountdown.svg

It won't last for that long, since it was a countdown clock. But I won't take it down(as long as it doesn't get automatically deleted), and if you wanted to see how it worked, you cold just download it and change the date it counted down to.