# CSS Textsize based on Container Width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is is possible to set the text size in CSS such that it adjusts to the container width?

I made an example for that. The left container is small which should make the font size smaller than for the right container. I know how this is done with JavaScript, but can I also be done with pure CSS?

[image]

Comment: display: inline-block; should work for you, EDIT: sorry read wrong.

Comment: That will not change the font size.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292001/how-to-set-font-size-based-on-container-size

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292001/how-to-set-font-size-based-on-container-size

Comment: I think you'll need JS

Comment: You can set text width with percent(%). I think it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use viewport units instead of pixels, points or em. It's a CSS3 property.

```
1vw: 1% of viewport width
1vh: 1% of viewport height
1vmin: 1vw or 1vh, whatever is smallest
1vmax: 1vw or 1vh, whatever is largest
```

More info **[here](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)**.

Comment: Does all mobile devices support viewport values?

Comment: @confile You can check the browser compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units