# wrap text inside DIV with CSS?

Tags: html, css

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wq07030y/), How do I wrap the content inside my DIV so it doesnt overlap my DIV? I know we can use

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

but I have over 100 of  these little "boxes" with numbers inside and I want everything to fit inside (about 4-5 digits long).

below is my css

thanks in advance

```
/* desk boxes*/
.desk_box_ver{ 
   width: 18px;
   height: 33px;
}   


.desk_box_hor{ 
  width: 23px;
  height: 10px;
}   


.desk_box_hor, .desk_box_ver { 
   position: absolute; 
   border: 4px solid black; 
   padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want the end result to be. If the number doesn't fit inside, what should happen?

Comment: Are you asking how to scale the font size in order to fit inside the box, scale the box to fit around the number, or...?

Comment: text-wrap property is not supported in any of the major browsers.

Comment: @DrydenLong yes I want the numbers to fit inside the box and not overlap

Comment: @Juhana nothing should happen.. I just dont want the numbers to overlap..

Comment: That still doesn't really clarify... Do you want the numbers to shrink or the box to grow?

Comment: @DrydenLong either, I'd like to see both solutions if possible so I can make a decision since I have multiple DIVs.

Comment: Obviously you want something to happen, otherwise you'd just use the code you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to scale the text based on the size of the container, see this post here: [how to set font size based on container size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292001/how-to-set-font-size-based-on-container-size)

The accepted answer has the best and most reliable solution.

To scale the container around the text, you can simply remove the `width` and `height` for the CSS involving the containers. Here is an updated version of your fiddle where I just deleted the width and height: http://jsfiddle.net/3qrxezjv/

Answer (score 0):

Delete this

```
.desk_box_hor{ 
   width: 23px;
   height: 10px;
 }
```

You are making the box larger than the numbers. They wont fit regardless, unless:

- you make the font smaller;
- white-space:wrap;
- make the box size dynamic with padding

**EDIT**

To answer your response below

You can remove the inline styles via JQuery as follows:

```
$('.desk_box_hor').attr('style', function(i, style)
   {
   $(this).attr("style", "");
});

$('.desk_box_ver').attr('style', function(i, style)
   {
   $(this).attr("style", "");
});
```

Then apply css classes properly

Comment: I cant really delete the sizing of them since I have a lot.. look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wq07030y/).. I have over 200 of them

Answer (score 0):

Instead of imposing a fixed `width`, you could use `min-width`. This way the box won't be smaller than its content:

```css
.desk_box_ver{ 
    min-width: 18px;
}   
.desk_box_hor{ 
    min-width: 23px;
}
```

```css
/* desk boxes*/
.desk_box_ver{ 
 min-width: 18px;
 height: 33px;
} 
.desk_box_ver:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.desk_box_hor{ 
 min-width: 23px;
 height: 10px;
} 
.desk_box_hor:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.desk_box_hor, .desk_box_ver { 
 position: absolute; 
 border: 4px solid black; 
 padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="desk_box_hor" id="desk_H15" data-rel="236" style="left:325px;top:50px;">18556</div>
<div class="desk_box_ver" id="desk_I06" data-rel="219" style="left:93px;top:100px;">25753</div>
```

Comment: I updated my fiddle to show you an example of what I really have.. If it does expand the width . will it overlap the one next to it?

Comment: @alda1234 Yes, if the boxes are close, they may overlap when they grow.