# Change font-size in relation to container?

Tags: css

Currently I display my article titles with a background of 90% width of the post thumbnail, placed on top of it. Since there's only room for 1 line of text in the title, there is rare occurrences where a character limit is needed. My question is if there's a way to instead of cutting the title short with a character limit, as I'm currently doing, scale down the font-size to fit the entire title?

Short and simple: If title goes over width of 90% of entry-header, shrink the font size to fit the max-size of 90%, so I won't have to use a character limit.

Finding JS solutions, but they use a set width. Also viewport units scales in relation to body, so that wouldn't work.

I'm just curious, as I can how this would be quite useful in designing WordPress-themes in general, if anyone got a specific solution. Thanks. :)

Comment: I believe this is more a general CSS/JS/HTML question, rather than one specific to WordPress; the right place for it would be StackOverflow.com.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292001/how-to-set-font-size-based-on-container-size

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container