# How to maximize the font size in a div as greater as it doesn't overflow?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have a `div` with a dynamic size (based on the mobile device size) and I want to maximize the font size based on this `div` size without cause the text to overflow (both x and y axis).

For example: in the code here I still can increase the font size until it overflows.

How can I achieve it ?

A pure css solution would be preferred.

```css
.section {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.maximal-font-size {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section maximal-font-size">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
</div>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/

Comment: @Adam good enough for my purpose, thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make font-size relative to parent div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693928/how-to-make-font-size-relative-to-parent-div)

Answer (score 0):

```
.section {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 3vw; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can adjust the values to find the right balance between font size and div size