# How can I make an H1 (or similar elements) scale to the width of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want the text to take up the entire width of the page so the height/font size will depend on the width of the page.

Comment: Make an image instead.

Comment: If using an image, you may want to [look into SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) so that it's not all pixelated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font scaling based on width of container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Comment: SVG was a GREAT idea, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set font size based on container size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292001/how-to-set-font-size-based-on-container-size)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this with vanilla CSS. You're probably going to want to use a JS library like [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you may be able to achieve the desired effect using viewport units

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/