# Is it possible to adapt font size to div width with CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, responsive-design, font-size

I have a div with `70%` width, and here’s what I want to do:

- Put some words in that div
- Adapt font size so that those words
  occupy all div width

[image]

---

Is this possible with only css? Here is my code:

```css
.parent {
  width:70%;
  height:auto;
  min-height:100px;
  background:red;
  font-size:10vw;
}
```

```html
Please help me to change the font-size dynamically to the parent class
<hr>
<div class="parent">
  This Text
</div>
```

> Note: the div **size is responsive**, this is important. Thanks in
>   advance!

Comment: you want to change font sise according to the content in the div right?

Comment: yes i want to fill the div with my text

Comment: Do you want height of div to be fixed or varying ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292001/how-to-set-font-size-based-on-container-size

Comment: Nice question this has a lot of potential its very useful if someone finds an answer to it or in future browsers calc function is subjected to better functionalities

Comment: try to put padding between font.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps not quite what you're looking for, but something - You can make both the font and the element relative to view width.

```css
p {
  font-size: 5vw;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<p>
  I'm a P!
</p>
```

Comment: This is as close as it gets. If your text is static, you can hardcode its width to however many vw's you need to get it just right. If you're dynamically generating text, CSS isn't enough and you need to mix in some JS.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to add `display: inline;` in your code

```css
.parent {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 10vw;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  This Text
</div>
```

Comment: It works well but maybe need improvements to work fully.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding this answer or the question, this is backwards, and doesn't solve the problem - adding `display: inline` to parent div adapts it's size to text, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

```
**You can change font-size:10vh;**
        .parent {
      width:70%;
      height:auto;
      min-height:100px;
      background:red;
      color:white;
      font-size:10vh;
    }
    Please help me to change the font-size dynamically to the parent class
    <hr>
    <div class="parent">
      Text
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes but I think you need to use JS(jQuery).

JS:

```
$(function(){

var box = $('.box');
var boxWith = box.width();

$('.box h1').css('font-size',boxWith);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/sdfaatp8/

Comment: I want fill the div with my text, not change the font-size same as div width, but its useful code, thanks.

Comment: Do you want to make the text fill up the div at position X?and if you can please make an image to show me what you want,thanks.

Comment: See the image above

Comment: I'm not a JS pro,but i thank this Stackoverflow will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container Sorry i can't help you out.

Answer (score -4):

Here, I Updated it.... [JS Fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/np5n8m8a/10/)

try to use

css

```
.parent 
 {
      width:70%;
      height:auto;
      min-height:100px;
      background:red;
      font-size:10vw;          
  }



span{
      display:inline-block;
      transform:scale(1.8,1);
      -webkit-transform:scale(3,1);
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <span>This Text</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: This won't work, because elements that are `display: inline` can't have their width or height set - it's always derived from their content.

Comment: My div has a width

Comment: If you change div width then you also have to change Scale for span too

Comment: You are not answering the question and you are giving a worse solution with scale property.